# How to prove there's not a.s. convergence from definition alone (or, at least not with reverse Borel Cantelli)?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

The definition of almost sure convergence seems very abstract to me:

$$ P( X_n \ \text{converges to} \ X) = 1$$

How do you work with this definition when you want to show that there isn't almost sure convergence, *without* using reverse Borel Cantelli (since I have not yet learned this in class, and I want more intuition with the definition itself).

Take for example a random sequence with $X_n = 1$ with probability $1/n$, and $0$ with probability $1 - 1/n$. I am pretty sure this is not converging to 0 almost surely, but how to prove that via the definition alone?

Comment: To prove this (assuming independence), one is more or less forced to rediscover Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: Without further assumptions on the sequence (such as independence of the random variables) it is not possible to say whether the sequence converges or not.

Comment: Yes, variables are independent. Isn't that obvious? (hope this doesn't sound rude, I genuinely want to know whether it is not obvious?)

Comment: Well, why should it be obvious? Obviously, also non-independent random variables can converge almost surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $0<\epsilon<1$ and fixed $n\ge 1$ (assuming independence),
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}\left(\sup_{m\ge n}{|X_m-0|}> \epsilon\right) &=\mathsf{P}\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n}\{
|X_m|>\epsilon\}\right)=1-\prod_{m\ge n}\mathsf{P}(|X_m|\le \epsilon) \\
&=1-\prod_{m\ge n}(1-m^{-1})=1.
\end{align}
Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\left(\sup_{m\ge n}{|X_m-0|}> \epsilon\right)\ne 0.
$$